# duplicated value

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I have this code that show for exemple, CA of this years, and CA_AN for the previous year.
The problem is in the CA_AN i got the some value as u showed in the picture.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqJzD.png)

```
    SELECT DATENAME(month, GL_DATEPIECE) AS 'MONTH', et_region as 'REGION', e.et_etablissement as 'STORE CODE',et_libelle as 'STORE NAME',
        CA=CONVERT(DECIMAL(15,2),sum(gl_totalttcdev)),

        CA_AN=(SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(15,2),sum(gl_totalttcdev))
        from piece
        left join etabliss as e1 on e1.et_etablissement= gp_etablissement

        where
CAST(GP_DATEPIECE AS DATE) BETWEEN  DATEADD(YEAR,-1,CAST(@DATED AS DATE))  and DATEADD(YEAR,-1,CAST(@DATEF AS DATE))
        group by et_etablissement, et_libelle
        ),

    from piece 
    left join etabliss as e on gp_etablissement=e.et_etablissement  
    and CAST(GP_DATEPIECE AS DATE) BETWEEN  CAST(@DATED AS DATE) and CAST(@DATEF AS DATE) 

    group by et_region,et_etablissement, et_libelle, DATENAME(month, GL_DATEPIECE)
    order by et_region,CA_AN DESC,et_etablissement
```

Comment: A https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve would make it easier to assist!

Comment: Need a bit of clarification.  Are you attempting to pull data from a given timeframe, and separately sum up the gl_totalttcdev column values for last year (CA_AN) and this year (CA)?

Comment: Yes exactly. I'm using a procedure : start & end date. The value for CA work just fine, but in CA_AN the query gives me the same CA_AN in both Febrary and March.

Comment: Also, which database type?  SQL Server, MySql, etc?

Comment: Sql server 2008

Comment: Working out a sample query now to show how you can SUM without using a subquery.  Just need a few mins...

Answer (score 0):

May require a few iterations, but here's a sample that you may be able to build from.  You can SUM results selectively based upon the date ranges for *current year* and *previous year*, without doing a subquery.  A bit easier to read, and may perform better.

This assumes [GP_DATEPIECE] is a date or datetime column.

```
DECLARE @StartDate date = '1/1/2019'
DECLARE @EndDate date = '4/30/2019'
DECLARE @StartDatePreviousYear date = DATEADD(YEAR, -1, @StartDate)
DECLARE @EndDatePreviousYear date = DATEADD(YEAR, -1, @EndDate)

SELECT
     DATENAME(month, [GL_DATEPIECE]) AS [MONTH]
    ,[et_region] AS [REGION]
    ,[e].[et_etablissement] AS [STORE CODE]
    ,[et_libelle] AS [STORE NAME]
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN [GP_DATEPIECE] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate THEN ISNULL([gl_totalttcdev], 0) ELSE 0 END) AS [CA]
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN [GP_DATEPIECE] BETWEEN @StartDatePreviousYear AND @EndDatePreviousYear THEN ISNULL([gl_totalttcdev], 0) ELSE 0 END) AS [CA_AN]
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN [GP_DATEPIECE] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [CurrentYearItemCount]
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN [GP_DATEPIECE] BETWEEN @StartDatePreviousYear AND @EndDatePreviousYear THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [PreviousYearItemCount]
FROM [piece]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [etabliss] AS [e] ON [piece].[gp_etablissement] = [e].[et_etablissement]
GROUP BY
     DATENAME(month, [GL_DATEPIECE])
    ,[et_region]
    ,[et_etablissement]
    ,[et_libelle]
ORDER BY
     [et_region] ASC
    ,[et_etablissement] ASC
```

Comment: Thank's you your solution works really fine and fast ! But just in your case, i have a problem when i'm using a calculation inside your case state : (CASE WHEN  [GP_DATEPIECE] BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate THEN ISNULL(sum(GP_TOTALTTCDEV)/count(distinct(GP_NUMERO)), 0) ELSE 0 END) AS [QUANTITE]

Comment: Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery. I juste want to do a calculation using your case with start and end date

Comment: please i need your help

Comment: You wouldn't be able to put aggregates (like `count`) inside a `case` statement.  But you can add another column to the query which returns the `distinct` count of `[GP_NUMERO]` within each start->end timeframe.  Give me a second, and I'll update my sample above to include it.

Comment: What does `[GP_NUMERO]` represent?  Is that like an order number?  Or customer number?